Can Polynomial Features Be Used in Logistic Regression and Random Forest Models?
I am working in Python to predict the treatment response of 43 patients using 10 predictors as input. I noticed that adding polynomial features to my models produces nearly perfect results.
I am wondering if it is appropriate to use polynomial features in this case?

Using polynomial features can be a double-edged sword, especially in a dataset with a small sample size like yours (43 patients). Here's an analysis of the situation:

Why Polynomial Features Might Produce Perfect Results

Overfitting:

Adding polynomial features significantly increases the model's complexity. With only 43 samples, the model can memorize the training data rather than generalizing, leading to overly optimistic results. This is a classic case of overfitting.

High Ratio of Features to Samples:

Expanding the feature set with polynomials rapidly increases the number of predictors (e.g., from 10 features to possibly dozens or hundreds, depending on the polynomial degree). With a small dataset, the model might exploit noise or spurious correlations.

Spurious Correlations:

Higher-order polynomial terms may capture irrelevant or coincidental patterns in the dataset, giving the illusion of "perfect" performance.

When Is It Appropriate to Use Polynomial Features?

Domain Knowledge Supports It:

If there's a known nonlinear relationship between predictors and the response variable, polynomial features might make sense. For example, quadratic relationships are common in physics or biology.

Regularization Is Applied:

To avoid overfitting, you should use regularization methods like Lasso or Ridge regression. These penalize large coefficients and help prevent the model from fitting noise.

Sufficient Data:

With only 43 samples, polynomial features can easily lead to an over-parameterized model. Typically, you'd want a much larger dataset to use polynomial features effectively.

How to Test Appropriateness of Polynomial Features

Cross-Validation:

Use cross-validation to evaluate model performance. If the performance significantly drops on validation sets, it’s a sign of overfitting.

Regularization:

Apply regularization techniques like Ridge or Lasso regression. These can help identify if the polynomial terms truly add predictive power or if they're just overfitting.

Feature Importance Analysis:

Check which polynomial terms are contributing significantly. If only a few terms are meaningful, you might manually include just those instead of generating all possible terms.

Compare with Simpler Models:

Benchmark your model with simpler approaches (e.g., linear regression or models without polynomial features). If the simpler model performs nearly as well, the added complexity may not be justified.

I think it's better that start with simpler models and prioritize interpretability, especially in small datasets and use polynomial features cautiously and ensure they're evaluated with rigorous validation. If polynomial features dramatically improve performance, ensure you aren’t overfitting by testing on unseen data or using cross-validation.
I hope this answer could help you.

Apollo, Thank you so much for your answer. You have added a lot to me. I have already done fivefold cross-validation for LR. It was 8.8 and 8.0 for train and test, respectively, while it was 1 and 8.2 for RF.

Cool, waleed almutairi. I recommend you Feature Engineering. I think it can help your accuracy problem. But you can't avoid overfitting for RF. To do this, you can reduce max_depth in my opinion.
